# Is this security concept suitable for a web app?

Tags: asp.net, security, web

I wondering whether the following security concept is suitable for a web app:

1) Login UI availabe only over SSL.

2) Login UI consists with 3 fields:

- List item
- User name,
- File upload box,
- Pin field.

File for upload box is *emailed to user during registration process*.

This file is a long sequence (few kilobytes or few dozens of kilobytes) of random bits.
This file scrambled using pin value, than its hash like SHA-512 calculated in an multi-layer manner, like so - many times calculate the hash, appending or prefixing the hash from previous iteration to last processed blob.

```
F(n) IS (
    IF n == 0 
    THEN HASH(SCRAMBLE(file, pin)) 
    ELSE HASH(IF n mod 2 == 0 THEN CONCAT(F(n-1), FILE) ELSE CONCAT(FILE, F(n-1));
```

Pin is displayed during registration on screen as image, so this pin is ONLY displayed on screen, but never transmitted to user as plain text.

Is this enough secure?
Thanks for comments.

Possible contexts or types of web apps:
a) business website (with payments processing in behalf of site owner).
b) intranet or corporate website with access to a special section for customers.

Comment: What is the context? Also, why are you emailing the user a file they just uploaded?

Comment: You're going to have a hard time answering this question.  Is it suitable for Fort Knox, probably not.  Is it suitable for an internal business application, probably not.  Context is necessary for us to understand if your solution fits the problem.

Comment: If you are going to require users to cope with managing a file as a credential instead of a password, why not use SSL client certificates instead of the upload box?

Comment: user113215, i stated that "File for upload box is emailed to user during registration process"...

Comment: bobince, good point. But i not sure, whether all users really want know, what the file it was (either certificate or not), and i not sure whether all browsers have the comportable UI with certificates. Also, if i publically state in email plain text that the attachment is a security certificate and it must be installed, an attacker can use this information as is.
Instead of certificate i thought to use a long blob (few kilobytes of random bits).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

The large file is sent via email which is not secure.  In addition you are requiring the user to upload each time (s)he logs on; (a) that's a total pain in the rear, and (b) most users are going to leave the file hanging around on their computer's disk somewhere.  The ratio of security : user inconvenience is extremely low, I wouldn't do it.

If you need to be extremely secure, use a strong password plus a true out of band, single-use token such as an SMS message that they need to request each and every time they use a new computer.  Use the password and the single-use token to authorize the download of a larger machine-specific cookie that is tied to their machine in some manner (e.g. device signature plus IP address of some kind), and re-require the use of the out-of-band SMS if anything doesn't match up.

Also, don't forget about phishing mitigations.

Comment: Thanks for the good points!